# Teradata SQL Compare Values for Group if it similar or not

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a data table like the below, I need to compare the `OfferID` for each `CustomerID` if they are similar or deffirent. I tried to get it by

```
CASE
        WHEN (COUNT (DISTINCT OfferID) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID)) = 1  THEN 'SAME_OFFER'
        ELSE 'DIFFERENT_OFFER'
    END AS STATUS
```

But it seems that `COUNT DISTINCT` does't work as a window function

```
|CustomerID|EffectiveDate|OfferID|
|----------+-------------+-------|
|123       |1-Jan-2021   |111    |
|123       |2-Jan-2021   |111    |
|123       |3-Jan-2021   |111    |
|133       |1-Jan-2021   |222    |
|133       |2-Jan-2021   |333    |
|144       |1-Jan-2021   |222    |
|144       |2-Jan-2021   |222    |
|144       |3-Jan-2021   |333    |
|144       |4-Jan-2021   |333    |
```

the desired output will be the below

```
|CustomerID|EffectiveDate|OfferID|Status         |
|----------+-------------+-------+---------------|
|123       |1-Jan-2021   |111    |Same_Offer     |
|123       |2-Jan-2021   |111    |Same_Offer     |
|123       |3-Jan-2021   |111    |Same_Offer     |
|133       |1-Jan-2021   |222    |DIFFERENT_OFFER|
|133       |2-Jan-2021   |333    |DIFFERENT_OFFER|
|144       |1-Jan-2021   |222    |DIFFERENT_OFFER|
|144       |2-Jan-2021   |222    |DIFFERENT_OFFER|
|144       |3-Jan-2021   |333    |DIFFERENT_OFFER|
|144       |4-Jan-2021   |333    |DIFFERENT_OFFER|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `min()` and `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(offerid) over (partition by customerid) = max(offerid) over (partition by customerid)
             then 'SAME_OFFER' else 'DIFFERENT_OFFER'
        end) as status
from t
```